# Are there any non-readability related reasons to NOT specifically use fixed width integers every single time?

Tags: c++, c

Let's say that we have `uint_least8_t var`, where, hypothetically speaking, `var` won't possibly ever exceed the value 255.
I know that's not how programming works and "possibly" and "ever" are a blasphemy, but, aside from complicating the code and making it less readable, what makes always using fixed width integers a bad idea?

Comment: It is best to use the natural `int` size of the machine unless you have good reason not to. I would say using different integer types for different quantities will make the code less readable, not more. Uh: the question was since edited.

Comment: Your system may be very bad/slow at manipulating, say, 16 bit quantities.

Comment: you will need more casting when you always use the most narrow type for each variable

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry for that, I don't know how I messed up that part when I wrote that those types simplify and improve readability, I edited it! Thanks for noticing, my bad!

Comment: My rule of thumb: Use fixed width types when your code depends on the size of the type.  After that use the type who's minimum mandated value is enough for you.

Comment: @WeatherVane: it was a long time ago when `int` meant word size of the CPU. Most (all?) 64-bit compilers use 32-bit `int`, for example.

Comment: In case you need a counter where you don't care if it overflows as 32 or 64 bit you might be better off using just `int` or `long` for best performance instead of saying int32_t (unnecessarily restricting yourself on 64 bit platform) or int64_t (being slow on 32 bit platform).

Comment: My rule of thumb: I use `size_t` for all container size/index related stuff. And I use fixed width types everywhere else (with sorter alias, like `s32`, etc.).

Comment: Inside of a function it doesn't really matter. Compilers will likely promote it to the CPU's wordsize & work with that regardless of what you use. Might as well accept that and use `int/long` to make it less surprising there. In interfaces where you might wish to communicate what range of values you accept & in structs you expect to have a lot of, I think the minimal-width typedefs are a great idea. The fixed-width typedefs are theoretically less portable because the standard doesn't guarantee their existence, & I'd avoid the fast typedefs because different libcs might define them differently.

Comment: Your code might not compile for a 36-bit mainframe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Performance is another reason.

Narrow operands require additional narrowing/widening instructions. This can't always be optimized away without side effects. And sometimes the optimizer just isn't smart enough and plays it safe.

Take the following contrived example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    auto tm1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    unsigned int n = 0;
    unsigned int x = 0;  // though, uint8_t would have been enough!
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        n += (x * i);
        x = (n + 1) & 0x7F;
    }
    auto tm2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << n << ", " << (tm2 - tm1) / 1.0s << " s" << endl;
}
```

If we change the type of `x` from `unsigned int` to `uint8_t`, the application becomes 15% slower (2s instead of 1.7s run time on x86-64 when compiled with GCC 7.2 `-O3` full optimization on).

Assembly with a [32-bit](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4es8pl) `x`:

```
.L2:
  imul eax, edx
  inc edx
  add ebx, eax
  lea eax, [rbx+1]
  and eax, 127
  cmp edx, 1000000000
  jne .L2
```

Assembly with an [8-bit](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/UwuqO8) `x`:

```
.L2:
  movzx eax, al    ; owww!
  imul eax, edx
  inc edx
  add ebp, eax
  lea eax, [rbp+1]
  and eax, 127
  cmp edx, 1000000000
  jne .L2
```

Answer (score 4):

Compatibility with other code, and not imposing arbitrary restrictions.

A large portion of the integer variables you use in a typical C program are array indices, object counts, etc. Such values are inherently *not representable* as fixed-width integer types whose width is known at the time of writing the program; the possible range varies by implementation. (This is related to the fact that a given C implementation is not Turing-equivalent; only an infinite family of implementations, via the [Transdichotomous model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transdichotomous_model) is). Cetainly you could *decide* that you only want to support up to 2^32 (for example) of a given thing, and thereby get by with using a fixed-width type, but it's anti-idiomatic, and such code won't be compatible with typical (including std lib) interfaces that use `size_t` and might be passing or accepting larger objects.